# Making an array by looping

Tags: java

Here's my code i need help on how to properly tokenize each token and put them on a array in each cycle of my loop and also how to get the sum of the array and how to get the farest distant value?

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

public class Data{ 
public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException{ 
  String Filename = "Data.txt" ; 
    String line;

      FileReader Filereader = new FileReader(Filename);
      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(Filereader);
      line = input.readLine(); 

      System.out.println("--- oOo ---");
      System.out.println("AVERAGE ACID LEVEL");
      System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");

        double[] nums = new double[13];
        int sum = 0;

      while ( line != null ) // continue until end of file 
      { 

        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line);



            for ( int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++ )
           {

              String temp = input.readLine();
              nums[i] = Double.parseDouble(temp);

              System.out.println(nums[i]);
           }

      } 
      input.close(); 

} 
    }
```

oh! heres the data on data.txt

```
5.6
6.2
6.0
5.5
5.7
6.1
7.4
5.5
5.5
6.3
6.4
4.0
6.9
```

any help would be greatly appreciated...
THANKS

Comment: If you are asking these questions, you must not have written this code. We aren't here to do your homework for you. Don't just paste code and say "add this and that".

Comment: I am still not sure why Homework tag was removed from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Well since your data values are on a new line each time, you don't need `StringTokenizer` as you can just read the value from the line

You also dont need to have a nested `for` loop in your `while` loop, each line is read once by the `while` loop, so basically within your while loop do this

1. Read value
2. Add to array (use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) so can have a dynamic length)
3. Add to sum
4. Compare if it is farest

Comment: +1 - This is (IMO) the right kind of answer for this kind of question.  It is important that the OP learns to do his own programming!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
```

instead of

```
line = input.readLine(); // it having the first value
```

because, You must read the file line by line.

```
while ( line != null ) // so only your loop is unbreakable
```

Dont copy and paste. Try to understand.

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) // This will read the file line by line till last value.
        {
            values[i] = Double.valueOf(line); 
            i++;                          // This is for finding the total number of values from the file.
        }

        Double sampleInput = 0.0;
        for(Double valueArray : values)
        {
            sampleInput = sampleInput + valueArray; // Atlast we sum all the array values.
        }

        Double output = (double) sampleInput/values.length;
```